# Last record from a pyodbc query doesn't process (to messaging system using stomp)

Tags: python, pyodbc, stomp, activemq-artemis

I'm querying a database, which returns 38 records. In the below example, all 38 print, but the last record is not sent to the messaging system, only the first 37. What am I missing here???

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' + connectionString)
cnxn.autocommit = True
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

sql = (sql statement that returns 38 records)

cursor.execute(sql)
print("Connected")
row = cursor.fetchone()

while row:

    conn = stomp.Connection([('this.that.sys', '61616')])
    conn.connect('user', 'pass', wait=True)
    print("Send " + row.id)  
    conn.send(destination='test1.topic::test1.test1.queue', body=row.payload)

    row = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.disconnect()
```

This outputs a list of all 38 IDs, but the last Payload doesn't publish to the queue.

I did some more testing. This is odd. It seems to depend on the records. They're between 7KB and 15KB. If I try a certain two, only the first published. A certain three, the all publish. Another certain three, the last one again doesn't publish.

How can I debug this?

Edit: I've done more experiments. Is Stomp not guarantee delivery? I don't get any errors, but sometimes the messages just don't arrive, especially the last one. I refactored my code a bit, which seems to maybe help a little. I don't know...

```
cursor.execute(sql)
print("Connected")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print("First " + row.id)
i = 1

try:
    conn = stomp.Connection([('this.that.sys', '61616')])
    conn.connect('user', 'pass', wait=True)
    while row:
        print(str(i))
        print("Send " + row.id + " " + row.status)
        conn.send('test1.topic::test1.test1.queue', row.payload)

        row = cursor.fetchone()
        i = i + 1
    conn.disconnect()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: %s" % e)
```

Comment: What library are you using to send your STOMP messages? Is the send method executing asynchronously? If so, then `disconnect` might be getting called before the send actually happens.

Comment: Hi Justin. Thanks. The library is just called stomp.py. Good thinking. I added a time.sleep(1) before the conn.disconnect(), and did a few experiments without losing the last message. Tricky.

Comment: Why fetchone and not fetchall?

Comment: The STOMP protocol supports the [`receipt` header](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Header_receipt) which you can use to get a reply back from the broker that your `SEND` frame was processed successfully. I'm not 100% sure that stomp.py supports this, but it should since it's part of the protocol specification.

Comment: Also, it might be worth [activating trace logging for STOMP on the broker](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html#logging). Then you can see exactly what the broker is receiving from the client (e.g. if it's receiving the `DISCONNECT` frame prematurely).

Comment: BTW, you definitely shouldn't be connecting & disconnecting to send a single message. That's a well-known anti-pattern and should be avoided if at all possible. Your second code snippet is better in this regard.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: I need to try a few of these other suggestions, but it looks like postponing the disconnect is preventing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `send` method executing asynchronously? If so, then `disconnect` might be getting called before the send actually happens. Therefore, you might try delaying invocation of the `disconnect` method.

It's also worth noting that the STOMP protocol supports the [`receipt` header](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Header_receipt) which you can use to get a reply back from the broker ensuring that your SEND frame was processed successfully. I'm not 100% sure that stomp.py supports this, but it should since it's part of the protocol specification.

Also, it might be worth [activating trace logging for STOMP](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html#logging) on the broker. Then you can see exactly what the broker is receiving from the client (e.g. if it's receiving the `DISCONNECT` frame prematurely).

Lastly, you definitely shouldn't be connecting & disconnecting to send a single message. That's a well-known anti-pattern and should be avoided if at all possible. Your second code snippet is better in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I would change it:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' + connectionString)
cnxn.autocommit = True
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

sql = (sql statement that returns 38 records)

cursor.execute(sql)
print("Connected")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:

    conn = stomp.Connection([('this.that.sys', '61616')])
    conn.connect('user', 'pass', wait=True)
    print("Send " + row.id)  
    conn.send(destination='test1.topic::test1.test1.queue', body=row.payload)
    conn.disconnect()
```

Comment: Connecting & disconnecting to send a single message is a well-known anti-pattern and should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: My answer was related to the question regarding data fetching while you comment is not related to his question

Comment: As far as I can tell the question actually isn't about data fetching. He clearly says he's fetching all 38 records. The problem is that only 37 are being sent to the message broker. Therefore the failure is related to sending the messages via the STOMP client, and that's what my comment was addressing. Why do you think the problem is with fetching the data?

Comment: If you have read the entire question you would notice that he tried connecting and disconnecting only once and the issue was still there

Comment: I understand that maintaining a single connection doesn't solve the problem. I never expected that it would. However, the fact remains that connecting & disconnecting to send a single message is a well-known anti-pattern and should be avoided if at all possible.